# Get quick access to assets, events

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, erc-721, nft, erc-1155

How do sites like Opensea get all their data so fast? Because getting the data from the blockchain and fetching the tokenURi's takes a lot of time. So I thought they might store all the assets, events, users in a database, but wouldn't that be a huge amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

> How do sites like Opensea get all their data so fast?

They run their own client node. And you can too - see the [Nodes and Clients](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/) section of the official site.

Comment: Don't they use Alchemy so they don't have to run their own node? They're featured in Alchemy's home page that's why I'm guessing.